# SVG pattern fill misalignment in Chrome/FF

Tags: svg

I'm working on a mapping project and using SVG <image> elements as tiles always shows a seam between them. I can avoid the seams if I use <rect> elements with the css property "shape-rendering: crispEdges". However, when I try to fill these <rect> elements with a pattern that contains the tile image, there is some inconsistency in the alignment of the pattern in Chrome and FF (I'm using Chrome 45 and FF 41 right now).

I've isolated the issue in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1nfy3r/3/). All of the transforms, svg size, rect size, etc are directly from the project I'm working on and it should be assumed they can't be changed. I can only change the pattern (or if there's a attribute/property like "shape-rendering: crispEdges" for <image> elements I can change that).

How can I get the pattern tile image to fully cover, and be properly aligned with, the <rect>?

HTML

```
<!-- change background from white to black to see what's going on -->

<!-- The SVG is large. The <rect> can be located a bit to the right of the center of the SVG -->
<!-- When BG is black, you can see a white edge on the left and bottom -->
<!-- When BG is white, you can see a dark edge on the top and right -->
<body style="background: white;">
    <div style="position: fixed; x: 0; y: 0;">
        <button onclick="whiteBG()">White BG</button>
        <button onclick="blackBG()">Black BG</button>
    </div>
    <svg height="1965" version="1.1" width="5760" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <pattern x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="patternSieyywid32k">
                <!-- image is base64 encoded 415 x 512 image -->
                <image  xlink:href="data:image/jpg;base64,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" 
                       x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <g transform="matrix(0.0049,0,0,0.0049,101.5334,3349.9742)" style="display: inline;">
            <rect x="641958.5514" y="-516667.078" width="28275.123699999996" height="32099.475199999986" fill="url('#patternSieyywid32k')" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

JS

```
var whiteBG = function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = '#FFF';
}

var blackBG = function() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = '#000';
}
```

Comment: image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges any good to you (on Firefox of course) image-rendering: pixelated might work on Chrome.

Comment: Thing of what you are doing here.  You are taking a 451x512 bitmap and scaling it to 138.548x157.287 pixels, then positioning it at (3247.130,818.3055) and hoping it will come out pixel perfect.  You might need to consider a different approach.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I was under the impression that the css property "shape-rendering: crispEdges" caused the rect element to basically "snap-to-pixel", thereby making it pixel perfect. It appears that's what it does in my project because the seams disappear. I assumed that if the rect elements were pixel perfect, the  pattern image should be able to align properly. I guess it doesn't work that way, though. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with for this issue was to go back to using image elements, but instead of letting the browser handle the transform, I removed the transform from the group element and used some JS code to apply the transforms manually and update the x, y, width, and height attributes of each image element. Doing it this way, I have control over how to round the result to achieve pixel perfect tiles.